# XML Schema order indicators confusion

Tags: xml, xsd

I've been studying up how to write an XML Schema and I'm stumped on XSD ordering indicators like `xs:sequence`, `xs:all`, `xs:choice`. There seem to be only 3 of them and they're required in complex types. But what if I have the XML like the following:

```
<row>
    <name>John</name>
    <city>LA</city>
    <country>France</country>
</row>
```

In which the 3 elements inside `<row/>` can appear in any order i.e.  can appear before `<city>` and `<name>` etc. like this:

```
<row>
    <country>France</country>
    <city>LA</city>
    <name>John</name>
</row>
```

Does this mean I'll have specify a new `<xs:sequence>` for each sequence of elements. What if I have something like 20 elements with no specific order. Is there some shortcut here? Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**: I can't use `<xs:all>` because I might leave some elements. All of them are not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer to this question. Instead of using `<xs:all>` use `<xs:choice>` with `minOccurs="0"` and `maxOccurs="unbounded"`. Now the elements are not only optional they can also appear in any order.

```
<xs:element name="row">
 <xs:complexType>
   <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
     <xs:element name="name" /> 
     <xs:element name="city" /> 
     <xs:element name="country" />
   </xs:choice>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: FWIW I don't think that's the same at all.  This schema allows what it looks like - *any* number of child elements, each of which could be either of the three.  Is it valid to have a `<row>` contain five `<name>` children and nothing else?  This schema allows that.  Newt's answer is closer to what it sounds like you want.

Answer (score 2):

`<xsl:all>` is still your correct answer here I believe. Each element inside an `<xs:all>` compositor can have a `minOccurs` attribute of zero. The result is a set of elements which may occur in any order and any element may occur exactly zero or one times. For example, the below requires that `row` contains one `name` element, zero or one `city` elements and zero or one `country` elements in any order.

```
<xs:element name="row"> 
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all> 
            <xs:element ref="name"/> 
            <xs:element ref="city" minOccurs='0'/> 
            <xs:element ref="country" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
```

I may have misunderstood your requirement though.

Comment: But what if I they can occur more than one times?

Comment: So... you have three elements, all of which can occur zero or more times. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, 3 or more elements which can occur zero or more times and in no specific order.

Answer (score 1):

`<xs:all>` permits items in any order. Just use it instead of `<xs:sequence>`.

Comment: Well, your original question was only about order.